# How to create private Calendar events that only my app can read & write?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, private, android-calendar

This is not for a Calendar app, but something else that requires the Calendar Event functionality.

Is there any way in Android to use the [Android Calendar API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) to create events that:

1. only my app can see (i.e. other apps cannot see these events).
2. I can read those events created by my app only, I dont want to read the events created by other apps.

Comment: If you don't want it public then you'll have to create your own database of events and handle them in your own code.

Comment: So this means that if I want to use the Calendar API functions like reminders when events are going to start and all that - i have write all that myself (using something like alarmmanager) and cannot use the built in calendar API at all - is that correct?